# Strange screen flickering

Tags: nvidia

I got some troubles with I think its my nvidia drivers in ubuntu. I tried many different answers from other users but it never really solved it so maybe any of you can help me fix this :) My laptop is a Lenovo Y500 with a GT 650M graphic card and I am using ubuntu 14.04.1.

Most stuff seems to be working correctly but the moment my laptop uses any dark colours the screens starts flickering really bad and it is nearly impossible to navigate through it. I uploaded a video so you can see it on a movie but it happens everywhere there are dark colours (even while booting till the moment I hit the desktop although sometimes it kicks in later instead of immidiatly). In the movie you also see shortly when the yellow light comes in the flickering stops. Here is the link: http://youtu.be/7wsctkwNylI

I tried alot of different drivers but none so far work, most of them even made that my ubuntu could not start up anymore after the updates ubuntu would start booting and my laptop will just automatically turn off while booting. After that using alternatives like booting in the rootshell to remove the drivers wasnt possible either so i ended up reinstalling ubuntu everytime.

I considered that my graphic card might be failing but the problems started immediately after the first installation of ubuntu.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Seems [Nouveau](http://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/) accelerated Open Source driver for nVidia cards is not working well for your device. Proceed with installation of [BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia).